# How to customize Auth::user() columns with foreign key? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-authentication

Firstly, everytime we login in laravel, the default is that the user(table) is always accessible by just using **Auth::user()**.

See 2 tables below: 
 
[image]
**My struggle** is, how can I add subscriber's columns to users(table) using subscriber_id from user table as foreign key.

**My expectation** is, I want all these(below) to be globally accessible after I logged in.

```
Auth::user()->name
Auth::user()->age
Auth::user()->gender
Auth::user()->marital_status
Auth::user()->subscriber_id
Auth::user()->subscriber_name
Auth::user()->subscriber_status
Auth::user()->subscriber_created_at
Auth::user()->subscriber_created_at
```

I been searching for an answer on google but none helps. I wish someone could help me to this.

Comment: Could add a relationship on the User model that references the subscribers table.

Comment: @Adam that is my thought Sir. Could you teach me how to Sir. Sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Set the relationship on Users model.

Example, for a one to one relation:

```
public function subscriber()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Subscribers', 'id', 'subscriber_id');
}
```

Comment: done putting that Sir. My next question is how to access the columns of subscriber? I tried this "Auth::subscriber()->name" but returns error message "Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::subscriber does not exist."

Comment: This code set the relationship, the better way is on your controller:
$subscriber = Auth::User()->subscriber()->first();
Them pass to the view, and access like $subscriber->name
Or you can access direct with
Auth::User()->subscriber()->first()->name

Comment: I got it Sir thank you. This one works "Auth::user()->subscriber->name"

Answer (score 0):

I created Subscriber.php(model) consisting column above, and then I put below codes in my User.php(model):

```
public function subscriber()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Subscriber', 'id', 'subscriber_id');
}
```

And then to access all columns, I did these:

```
Auth::user()->name
Auth::user()->age
Auth::user()->gender
Auth::user()->marital_status
Auth::user()->subscriber_id

Auth::user()->subscriber->id
Auth::user()->subscriber->name
Auth::user()->subscriber->status
Auth::user()->subscriber->created_at
Auth::user()->subscriber->updated_at
```