# How can I link and access other table after logging in (laravel)

Tags: laravel

I have table named `admin`, I want `admin` table to be globally accessible after logging in to dashboard. And also, I want to display the **name** of admin who is logging in the website.

I try this way but does not run https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYTqb.png. And in the blade this code I tried in blade `{{ admin()->name}}`

Is there any another way :(

Comment: In what file is your `admin` function defined? Also, please paste the code of your function into the question, it helps more that linking to an image of some code.

Comment: it's helper function

Comment: helper.php ( laravel helper function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wish to display the name of admin after logging in. Then you can create & add `admin` function inside **App/User.php**. You can choose one from the two methods below.

**(Example 1)**

```
public function admin()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Admin', 'id', 'admin_id');
}
```

**(Example 2)**

```
public function admin(){
    $admin = DB::table('admins')
        ->select('name')
        ->where('admins.id', this->admin_id)
        ->first();
    return $admin;
}
```

Take note: `$this->admin_id` is a column from users table

---

Then you can display the admin's name like these below:

```
{{ Auth::user()->admin()->name }}
```

[Other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129302/how-to-customize-authuser-columns-with-foreign-key-laravel)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the user is logged in and if so you can do it as following:

In blade file:

```
@if(Auth::check())  <--- Check if user logged in
  {{Auth::user()->name}}
@endif
```

But please note that this checks if the user logged in but not the user roles/permissions. If you want only to show when the user is admin, you need to check user roles also.

Comment: i know this one i need to show the admin name not user name!

Comment: You say `the name of admin who's login is appear in the main website`. What do you mean by `admin name`? Is there only one admin? Or is the user associated with an admin?`